# Firebase Analytics Rest API

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to get firebase analytics data using Rest API but as per best of my knowledge, I need Profile ID to get analytics data. To get profile ID there needs to be a property and view under GA Dashboard which seems like not to be supported for firebase analytics app.

Please let me know how can I get analytics data for firebase app using REST API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no REST API for Google Analytics for Firebase.  You have to export your data to BigQuery, then you can do what you want with it from there.

Comment: I've linked firebase analytics app to BigQuery and getting raw data under app_events and app_events_intraday tables.

Our major requirement behind using BigQuery is to get analytics data that we get under Firebase analytics dashboard e.g. active_users, new users, audience geo locations and so on.

Can I get google analytics historic data like I get it on Firebase analytics dashboard? Also, I get this data by downloading CSV from the same dashboard but that is a manual approach, I am looking to automate it.

Please acquaint me with the right approach to get analytics data for firebase app

Comment: If you have a second question that's different from the first, please ask it separately.

Comment: I've asked it here separately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063625/get-firebase-analytics-historic-data-using-bigquery. Please let me know. Thanks!