# Get Firebase Analytics Historic Data using BigQuery

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I've linked firebase analytics app to BigQuery and getting raw data under app_events and app_events_intraday tables.

Our major requirement behind using BigQuery is to get analytics data that we get under Firebase analytics dashboard e.g. active_users, new users, audience geo locations and so on.

We can get these kinds of data using GA REST API for web applications but here we are using firebase app for mobile application and we came to know that BigQuery is the only option to get analytics data.

Can I get google analytics historic data like I get it on Firebase analytics dashboard?
Also, I get this data by downloading CSV from the same dashboard but that is a manual approach and I am looking to automate it.

Please acquaint me with the right approach to get analytics data for firebase app.

Thanks!