# Firebase database(Send analytics data using Firebase REST API) into Firebase Dashboard Analytic data

Tags: wpf, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-analytics

We are integrating Firebase with our android(Xamarin Android) and windows(WPF) flavor of same application.

We chosen Firebase just to collect analytics information(User Events, User Properties and Crash logs and all).

For android we have used Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics nuget package. Now we are able to view user analytics data from Firebase dashboard.

But for windows, there is only one option to integrate Firebase which is using Firebase REST api. But that integration mainly creates Firebase database and it will update the sending data. But I am not sure how to get user analytics information out of it?

We thought of using common analytics tool for both android and windows so that we are looking for possible option to get analytics data from Firebase database.

Please help me to view analytics data in Firebase analytics dashboard from data present in Firebase database?

We are in analysis stage, alternate solution to get anlytics data for WPF application is also useful. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a REST API to read the Firebase Analytics data? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097892, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50975293

Comment: Not to read analytics data. I am updating data to Firebase database using REST Api, I want to know how to view those data as analytics data in Firebase dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no connection between the Firebase Realtime Database and Google Analytics for Firebase.

If you need such a connection, you will have to code it yourself with the available APIs. Note that there is only a Firebase SDK for Analytics on iOS and Android, so you'll have to use one of those if you go this route.

Alternatively, consider writing your analytics data straight to BigQuery, and analyze it there.