# How to list firebase projects which are linked to Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-api

I am trying to list all google analytics properties connected to a google account.

While this works fine using the google analytics management api, it seems the connected firebase projects are missing:

[image: image1]

While in the analytics web UI the firebase property is listed. I took a look at how Google itself queries for this data and they use some kind of internal API:

https://analyticssuitefrontend-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/search/entityHeaders

Result:

[image]

I tried adding a firebase related scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.readonly`) to my OAuth authorization but the property was still missing.

How can I query for the full list?

Comment: Where in the documentation does it state that The Google analytics apis would return data from firebase analytics?

Comment: @DaImTo Maybe I misunderstood. Could it be that these are two completely separate analytics, which are just displayed in the same webpage? As in different metrics and dimensions etc.

Comment: To my knowledge they are two completely different systems that have almost no communication between them.  Firebase analytics should be accessed though their api if they have one.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50974885/1841839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DaImTo [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867324/how-to-list-firebase-projects-which-are-linked-to-google-analytics/54923673#comment96505493_54867324) these systems are separate and firebase analytics data can not be queried via the google analytics API. This also holds true for listing connected firebase projects.

The confusion might arise, because google provides access to firebase analytics data under the hood of the google analytics website.